# What are the best practices for converting php website to nextjs website?

Tags: seo, html, php, technical-seo, on-page-seo

I have a website built using HTML and PHP. I want to revamp the design of the website but the code is literally messed up. It contains a lot of duplicate and junk code and cleaning it will be too much effort rather than creating it from scratch.

I am planning to use nextjs instead of HTML and PHP for this revamp.

Now my major concern is SEO.

The URL's of this website is ending with `.php`.

Example `www.abc.com/123.php` but in nextjs it will be something like this `www.abc.com/123`. This can mess up the off-page SEO of the website.

Is there a way to achieve this revamp without impacting the off-page SEO of the website?

Any lead will helpful

Thank you!!

Comment: The easiest way is to do a 301 redirect in **.htaccess**, if you are using apache